# WordPress - Taxonomy MetaData RETRIEVE

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using https://github.com/bainternet/My-Meta-Box to create MetaData in my taxonomy "group"

How do I retrieve that data? As of right now I have each group ID, but i have no idea how to retrieve the MetaData.

Comment: Here is some good information. Just enter your question title there. [ask me first]:http://google.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just figured it out.  Unfortunately, https://github.com/bainternet/My-Meta-Box Uses the WP_Options table in the database, not the Meta table, like it should.

Here is how to get the information.

```
<?$meta = get_option('tax_meta_'.$category->term_id)?>
```

Comment: Nice job figuring it out.  As you point out, that's not where it should store it... deleting my answer!

Comment: Currently in Wordpress it seems that that's the only way to store additional metadata for taxonomies, that is by adding them to WordPress options (`wp_options` table). So it is not specifically My-Meta-Box's fault... at least as far as I know...